# Issues with menu taking up 100% of div it's in

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu and I want it to take up 100% of the space that it is in.  It stops when the last menu item is done.  Here is my style html and my style sheet.  The div that the menu is in takes up exactly the amount of space that I want it to so now I'm just trying to figure out how to get the mneu control to do the same.  All help is appreciated!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
               My New website
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Products"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Get Inspired" Value="Get Inspired"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Flooring Guide" Value="Flooring Guide"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Environmental Commitment" Value="Environmental Commitment">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact" Value="Contact"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>


/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body   
{
background: #b6b7bc;
font-size: .80em;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans- serif;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #696969;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
color: #034af3;
}

a:hover
{
color: #1d60ff;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
color: #034af3;
}

p
{
margin-bottom: 10px;
line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
font-size: 1.5em;
color: #666666;
font-variant: small-caps;
text-transform: none;
font-weight: 200;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
font-size: 1.6em;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
width: 1150px;

margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
border: 1px solid #496077;
}

.header
{
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background: #4b6c9e;
width: 100%;
}

.header h1
{
font-weight: 700;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
color: #f9f9f9;
border: none;
line-height: 2em;
font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
padding: 0px 12px;
margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
min-height: 420px;
}

.leftCol
{
padding: 6px 0px;
margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
width: 200px;
min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
 {
color: #4e5766;
padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
line-height: normal;
}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
background-color:#3a4f63;
width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: #465c71;
border: 1px #4e667d solid;
color: #dde4ec;
display: block;
line-height: 1.35em;
padding: 4px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #bfcbd6;
color: #465c71;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #465c71;
color: #cfdbe6;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
margin: 1em 0px;
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
display: inline;
}

legend 
{
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: 600;
padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
width: 320px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
width: 320px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
clear: both;
}

.title
{
display: block;
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
font-size: 1.1em;
display: block;
text-align: right;
padding: 10px;
color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
font-size: 1.2em;
color: Red;
}

.bold
{
font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
text-align: right;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: please provide generated html, no ASP, or even better, set up a jsFiddle...

Comment: I'm using a control that comes with visual studio and it isn't showing up the menu when I put it into jsFiddle.

Comment: I've tried using a html based menu as well, but it keeps messing up when I try to add in a submenu.

Comment: Copy the HTML from your browser (view source), not the source code from visual studio